# Who makes this shower faucet handle (logo identification)?

Tags: bathroom, shower, faucet

Who makes this shower faucet handle?

[image: Faucet Handle Logo]

It's slightly broken, I'd like to get a replacement part, but I have no idea what company this is. Does anyone recognize this logo, or know how I might go about finding the answer myself?

I've done image searches, I've asked a few relatively knowledgeable vendors (who are searching on my behalf but haven't found it yet), and I can't find any more concrete information on either handle (although I may yet dig further behind the faceplate to look for more branding information).

Comment: How old is it?  The company may have gone out of business, or changed logos.

Comment: Old enough for that to be plausible. It's just shy of ten years since it was installed.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the nature of "slightly broken"?

Comment: Sure -- at the end of the cap was a small recess the size of a screw head, with a smaller hole for the shaft of the screw. You'd put a screw in there to attach it to the handle underneath, and then put a little plug over the recess to hide the whole thing. At one point, when putting the cap back on, I tightened the screw too much, cracked the plastic at the bottom of the recess so the cap would now turn without turning the handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very helpful support contact at Moen managed to put me in touch with someone at Amati Canada, who suggests that it is an "American Sole" unit. I can't find any information that suggests that's a manufacturer, or a line of products or anything -- so I can't corroborate, but at least I may be on the path to finding out who makes it.

Incidentally, in the meantime, I managed to find a workaround for repairing the part that was broken (I found a small plastic bit that sits firmly in the recess and can be screwed on, acting as a sort of bridge between the screw and the cap, so that when you turn the cap, it turns the handle again). It's not a perfect fix, but it's more than adequate for my needs. If I can get the part replaced, I may still, but it's nice to have options.

Comment: Hi Geoffrey were you able to find out who the company was? Our shower just broke too and the only identifier is the exact same logo! Trying very hard to find the replacement shower cartridge valve that just broke.

Comment: @Lina see my answer below

Comment: No, I wasn't able to find anything solid at the time, and that's now my previous house, but I agree with SpectralGhost, Sol looks like a solid lead, so I'd go with it.

Answer (score 0):

As best as I can tell, the brand for that is [Sol](http://www.eurosanitari.com/) an Italian manufacturer. The logo looks identical.